# How to change the percentage according to the recorded audio volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

As shown on the below figure (***Source*** : **Disney spot light app** https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/disney-spotlight-karaoke/id455072135?mt=8)

I want to **change the percentage value, depends on recorded sound while recording audio.**

if we keep the device in the quite silent places, the peracentage not to be changed..

If we keep the device at a full loudly place, song/ voice / machine sound or any sound.. the percentage needs to be increase according to the volume recorded.

How can we do it in iOS using objective c

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you're using an `AVAudioRecorder` to record your sounds, you can call:

```
[audioRecorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];
```

before starting to record in order to enable the audio-level metering. Then at any time you can call:

```
[audioRecorder updateMeters];
float audioPower = [audioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0]; // You can change 0 according to your input channels
```

`audioPower` will give you a float value between -160 and 0 dB, that you then can adapt to your needs.

If you want to constantly poll the audio level you can call the code above through an `NSTimer` action or use an `NSOperationQueue`

Check [AVAudioRecorder reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/averagePowerForChannel%3a) for more details on these methods

Comment: Care to share some of your code? How do you track the volume level?